Would ETC be useful for precision small arms in the near future?
I'm still working on that campaign from my other question about bio weapons and I've started working on coming up with weapons.
Brief summary: Its 2065, the world is in a state of constant proxy wars and the players in my campaign have to fight their way to sabotage a brand new super weapon (or perhaps use it themselves).
Most of the weapons in this world are just really fancy traditional firearms, but I want to give one of the main adversaries something a bit different.
What I'm picturing is a bullpup, semi auto .50 caliber rifle that uses ETC instead of a traditional firing mechanism.

Electrothermal-chemical (ETC) technology is an attempt to increase accuracy and muzzle energy of future tank, artillery, and close-in weapon system guns by improving the predictability and rate of expansion of propellants inside the barrel.
An electrothermal-chemical gun uses a plasma cartridge to ignite and control the ammunition's propellant, using electrical energy to trigger the process. ETC increases the performance of conventional solid propellants, reduces the effect of temperature on propellant expansion and allows for more advanced, higher density propellants to be used.

The goal being that this rifle would have a higher muzzle velocity and therefore (along with other precision features) more accuracy and more kinetic energy than a regular .50 BMG rifle whilst being roughly the same size and weight.
Most large bore weapons in this universe use ETC ranging from 30mm up to 140mm because of its advantages and because its not too sci-fi for 2065. Would it have any noticeable benefit for something as small as a .50 caliber round?
If ETC is a no-go, I was also considering giving them cartridges with some sort of exotic propellant consisting of a porous foam (Like Styrofoam) that's injected into cartridge's. As with ETC the goal is to make the propellant burn as evenly and consistently as possible to maximize muzzle velocity.

I added the summary info about ETC. Never trust a link in general, but in specific, never force your audience to go hunting for information - especially when it's just the definition of an abbreviation. Always bring a summary into your post. Thanks.

At present, this is plausible enough for fiction
The basic idea, of dumping a lot of energy into a propellant charge to initiate it faster and more predictably, seems sound.
The difficulty of doing this in small arms is that it needs a significant supply of electricity, too much for current battery technology to handle easily. Carrying a generator around will not be welcomed by infantry, on the grounds of both weight and noise.
A further problem is disposing of heat. In conventional firearms, much of it can be disposed of with the cartridge case. However, most ETC concepts are for caseless cartridges.
However, making this a major point in your story is a risk in at least two ways:

It may become obsolete, if a different way of initiating propellant is invented, and ETC suddenly becomes a mark of "yesterday's future."

Making a fuss over weapons technology, especially fictional technology, is not a fool-proof way to create an interesting story. If both sides in a conflict have it, it isn't very interesting. If only one side has it, it's only interesting if it makes a major difference to the story. Otherwise it is pointless detail that won't engage most readers.



Agree, power supply and weight are in the top three problems. #3 being heat, and how to get rid of it in such a small platform. especially since etc gus are caseless and dont have the ejected brass to dump heat into.

@Gillgamesh: Good point, added.

Agree re the risk of becoming obsolete - GDW went to a lot of trouble when creating the Traveller 2300 TTRPG back in the 1980s to extrapolate from the H&K G11 and make their "cheap" future assault rifles merely caseless and their advanced weapons use binary propellants (and maybe even ETC).  Of course, the G11 was basically abandoned and their "futuristic" small arms now look a bit clunky with the hindsight of another 4 decades of small arms development.

Just for clarity. this isn't a book I'm writing, its a heavily modified D&D campaign so this is intended to be a weapon the players can potentially acquire themselves which is why I wanted it to be a little exotic and justify it being more powerful in a semi realistic way.

This is perfectly reasonable for worldbuilding, but it's a trivial piece of window dressing
From a rifle's perspective, all Electrothermal-Chemical (ETC) tech does is replace the primer. It makes sense in a contemporary context because the amount of propellant in tank/artillery and bigger guns is so much and the volume it expands into so great that the improvement in efficiency is measurable and desirable.
But in a rifle... Compared to a tank the propellant in even a .50 rifle is a drop in the bucket. Improving efficiency from (metaphorically) 99% to 99.8% is pretty much meaningless.
Therefore, it's a cool bit of window dressing in your story, but if you're looking for "realistic," then it's unlikely to ever happen. Improving the quality of the propellant itself would be more efficient because primers are cheap and ETC, in comparison, isn't.
Note that whenever someone asks for something "realistic" or "as realistic as possible" I'm always quick to point out that if you don't include economics then you're not being "realistic" at all. Nobody would waste money on an incremental improvement... well, maybe the U.S. government would... but you know what I mean.

Fair, I might merge both ideas then, an ETC gun that uses an exotic propellant.

I'm a slight bit confused as to the last section of your answer as I don't recall asking for realism? And for context, in the universe I'm working on, the two main superpowers have essentially been in a cold war for the past century, they're involved in multiple proxy wars simultaneously and military spending rises every year to constantly one up each other in these wars. War is practically a way of life for them, so any advancement, no matter how small, is seen as an advantage worth putting money into.

@ChellCPlus No, you didn't mention realism, but consider the remainder of your second comment. A century of war... and yet their economies remain strong enough to put money into any advancement no matter how small? That's what I mean by people ignoring economics. After a century of non-stop war (even by proxy) whole sections of the planet would be in economic ruin and many fighting with sticks and stones.

By super powers I mean like the USA taking over most of north America and some of south America and the USSR taking over much of Asia (They're different countries in the plot). The wars are proxies fought in between the two, in Europe and Africa, they simply provide support to these puppet states. But by and large these two superpowers are fairly normal internally. The biggest difference is they take the USAs defense economy to an extreme, everyone makes money off these wars somehow.

Frame Challenge
Are we wanting something different in order to be cool and exotic - or is there a practical purpose for this in your world?
Or to put it another way:
What is it that the current .50 cal round can't do, that you need it to do in your world?
Opponents wearing Armour? SLAP or API rounds.
Opponents in cover? HE rounds.
Opponents at Range? Match-grade, Sub-MOA rounds.
To give clarity - a Match-Grade round out of a precision rifle is capable of reaching out and touching bad guys at 3.4 Km away.
If you want to be different for the sake of difference - things I would look at:

Ways to reduce the felt-recoil of the round

Mounting system for the Weapon on a human

Integrated ammunition feeding system that eliminates the need for magazine/belt changes

Smart projectiles


If you can reduce the felt-recoil, you can use bigger or heavier projectiles - which means you can either fit more stuff into them (Armour piercing cores, Explosive etc.) or do things like have them be self-guided etc.
A Mounting system just means you can easily carry a heavier weapons system which means more gadgets and doo-dads (and also less felt recoil) and less fatigue from hauling it around.
Having a system that eliminates the need for a manual reload that was cheap and reliable would be great (no more fumbling magazines and having to take cover mid fire-fight)
And Smart projectiles - this is probably the biggest. If you look at the last 40 ish years of small-arms development, one of the major recurring themes is how to increase first hit probability.
We've tried Sub-calibre sabot rounds, 2 and 3 round bursts, Flachette rounds, some weird shotgun hybrid rounds etc. All with the same goal of making sure that when the soldier pulls the trigger on the initial engagement, their chance of hitting what they are aiming at is maximised.
Fancy propellant is all well and nice (and TBH - sounds cool) - but for something that would really make a difference - Felt Recoil and Smart Projectiles.
